# Parsing dictionary type data from text file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

My original input file is as follows (a total 1.3MB) :

```
 {
        "dataFrame": "AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=", 
        "decrypted": true, 
        "fcnt": 3, 
        "id": 1480528200533, 
        "port": 5, 
        "rssi": -116, 
        "sf_used": 10, 
        "snr": -8.5, 
        "timestamp": "2016-11-30T17:50:00.533Z"
    }, 
    {
        "dataFrame": "AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=", 
        "decrypted": true, 
        "fcnt": 5, 
        "id": 1480528235613, 
        "port": 5, 
        "rssi": -119, 
        "sf_used": 10, 
        "snr": -5.8, 
        "timestamp": "2016-11-30T17:50:35.613Z"
    },
```

when I run `infile = json.load(infile)`, I get an error as follow

```
**NO JSON object could be decoded**
```

It worked for a small portion of the same data..

Comment: What do you want to do ? Your code seems fine, is there an error of some sort ?

Comment: sorry, i edited my question. Thanks

Comment: This is a drastic change from the original question. The original question basically asked how to parse the data once it is read in. This question asks how to import something with the json module. Please undo the edits and post a separate question. In the new question, please provide a way to reproduce the problem: code AND input. Make a minimal example to see what goes wrong

Comment: The code you posted for example is no proper json because of the trailing comma. But that's apparently just an excerpt of the actual input. Please post everything we need to reproduce the issue. Use pastebin or something equivalent for big files, if you can't make them smaller

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just need to strip the `DEBUG:root:` part and the rest is a Python literal of some sort (with no embedded newlines), I'd suggest simplifying your code by letting Python parse the literal, with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

It's a little unclear what you're doing though so I can't provide exact code; your line is apparently three colon separated fields (you only skip one), where the final field is a `list` literal (you behave like it's a single `dict`).

Either way, once you've pruned away the logging prefixes, you can just do:

```
 value = ast.literal_eval(literal_string)
```

to let Python use its own literal parsing machinery to perform the conversion.

Comment: Hi there, I edited my code to a complete version. I am not sure where I need to use ast.literal_eval.. Basically I am trying to get rssi,dataFrame,time, snr, and gps into CSV from text file.

Comment: @James: What's confusing is that you claim the file contains `DEBUG:root:[{...`, but your code is splitting at the first colon, and processing index `0` of the resulting `list`. So it looks like you're processing `DEBUG` (or presumably, `INFO`/`WARNING`/`ERROR`) every time. Is the "portion of my data in text file" accurate, or did you include logging kruft that's not actually there?

Comment: I am currently getting those data from a server by using rest API, and the file that logging the data into text file has logging.debug(JSONresponse) at the very last line, where JSONresponse is request object. Am I supposed to log the data in a different way..? sorry i'm really novice to python.

Comment: @James: To be clear, are you parsing the data directly from the server's rest API, or is a separate script fetching the data, writing it to disk, and you're trying to parse the log? Logging is fine, but you (usually) wouldn't want to use it for data serialization.

Comment: It is a separate script fetching the data and trying to write into csv file. I fixed some parts in a script which I used to fetching the data from server, and now I am getting this format. Please refer to edited version

Comment: Okay, looks like it's just JSON. If you `import json`, then do `json.load` on an open file object containing those values (or `json.loads` on a `str` with the values), you should get the objects directly.

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate for your help. Would you be able to refer to my edited version? How should I progress in a way that I can filter out the data from there? I would like to filterout data,lsnr,rssi, and time.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through a dictionary will return the keys.

```
d={"a":1, "b":2}
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

will output "a" and "b".

Another way to loop through a dict is:

```
d={"a": 1, "b": 2}
for key, val in d.items():
    print(key, val)
```

In your code, the `line` should only contain the key.
I think you need to change your if block to:

```
for line, val in infile.items():
        if line.strip() in keep:
           csvlines.append(val.strip())
```

The above code is python 3. I think in python 2, instead of `items()` you would use `iteritems()`

I'm afraid I can't explain the `keyerror`. The keys should be strings, and indexing should work on strings.
Not completely sure why this goes wrong. But in any case you don't want to append the second character in the string-key, you want to append the value belonging to the key.

Could you look at line, before using it:

```
for line in infile:
    print(line) # <------------------- here
    if line[0].strip() in keep:
       csvlines.append(line[1].strip())
```

Comment: i am getting an error at if line[0].strip() in keep: and d.items ?

Comment: There you should remove the indexing, too. Just use line.strip()

Comment: line is a dict obj that does not support strip

Comment: I think line should be a string. You write the output of json.load to infile -> infile is a dict. Then you loop through the dict. Look at my answer, if you loop through a dict, the loop variable will be the keys of the dict. In your case the keys are strings -> line should be a string. Could you check that ?

Comment: I updated my question, I think it would be a good idea to look at line before using it.

Comment: Terminal output that I showed in the question is when I print (line) in for loop.

Comment: Could you update your question ? It's not clear to me how that output is produced. By printing line in the loop ? Then infile would be a dictionary with dictionaries as keys ? That seems strange to me. And there are no linebreaks. print() should break the line after every call to it. That means that the line variable is very long. I would like to see the input file and your exact code and the full error message. Could you try one of my loops, too ?

Comment: Hi Ihk, I am having a problem performing json.load(myInput) where myinput is my input text file. I updated my input file in the question. Thank you

Comment: You changed the entire question ? You should have started a separate question, the import problem is something completely different. Just pose the example that gave you the original error